# Bookmarklet to watch bright videos with a filter / dark mode

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, bookmarklet

I am currently watching a program tutorial on Youtube and the author of the videos does not have a dark theme set in his editor.

I usually use the Firefox addon DarkReader on all websites, which puts the websites into a darkmode.

But the addon does not work for videos.

That's why I'm looking for a possibility to put the videos, which are played by e.g. Youtube, into a darkmode.

Ideally would be a bookmarklet, which darkens the whole website and thereby also the video itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bookmarklet that darkens the web page as a whole and leaves the buttons behind still clickable:

```
javascript: (function () {
    var FilterOnTopDiv = document.createElement('div');
    FilterOnTopDiv.setAttribute('style','width: 100%;
                     height:100%;
                     z-index:999999;
                     position:fixed;
                     left:0px;
                     top:0px;
                     background-color:#000;
                     opacity: 0.25;
                     pointer-events:none;');
    document.body.appendChild(FilterOnTopDiv);
}());
```

The `opacity` is set to 0.25, that means when clicking on the bookmark several times, the web page is always 0.25 darker per click.

When reloading the web page, as usual with bookmarklets, everything is reset.

You can change the color of `background-color` to not only darken it, but also filter for other colors e.g. to filter out blue tones.

Tested on Firefox version 78.6.0esr(64-Bit).